# mask domain with subdomain with htaccess, its possible?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, prestashop-1.6

I have my domain: **mysite.com** with a section **mysite.com/blog.html** and I have a **subdomain blog.mysite.com** , I want when httpaccess recognize **mysite.com/blog.html** mask this url to **blog.mysite.com**

for example:

- mysite.com/blog.html mask to blog.mysite.com
- mysite.com/blog/one-post mask to blog.mysite.com/blog/one-post

its possible with httpaccess?

I´m reading and tried a lot examples but only redirect , if you type blog.mysite.com only redirect to mysite.com/blog.html not mask.

Thanks!

Comment: 1. Do you have control over server confg? 2. What URL do you want to show in browser?

Comment: Thanks! it´s the problem because is a web hosting I don´t have control to apache server config. I want show  blog.mysite.com , blog.mysite.com/blog/one-post